# How to update changes done by others in the main trunk to my local working copy situated in a branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need ensure that changes done by others in the main trunk get incorporated in my local working copy situated in a branch.

At the moment I am merging from trunk to branch, but I am not sure is this a the best option.

I am using `tortoisesvn` client and I would like to know if there is a proper feature for this in this client.

SVN version is 1.6.17

Comment: Read [the section on "Staying in Sync"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync) in the "Branching and Merging" section of the SVN documentation.  And update your client! 1.6.17 is over 4 years old; numerous bugs (particularly with merging) have been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is fine.

As long as you merge *all* revisions from trunk to your branch, you can later use the --reintegrate feature when merging back your changes into trunk.

Some people say 
"You keep your branch in sync with trunk"

Comment: thanks for your answer, just last one. do you know if it possible to use tortoisesvn for --reintegrate ??

Comment: you have to select "reintegrate in the 1st merge dialog in TSVN 1.6